# Errors occuring while attempting to install OpenMDAO. Issues related to cobyla suspected

Tags: openmdao

I am having trouble successfully installing OpenMDAO on Ubuntu. An issue with cobyla seems prevalent throughout the error messages. I've included the results of executing openmdao test and cobyla's setup.py below.

```
$ openmdo test
.........................................E........................................................................................................EE.....E.......EE.E.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.simple-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/examples/simple/test/test_simple.py", line 9, in <module>
        from openmdao.examples.simple.optimization_constrained import OptimizationConstrained
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.simple-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/examples/simple/optimization_constrained.py", line 8, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SLSQPdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_csv_post_processor.py", line 14, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SimpleCaseIterDriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_csvcase.py", line 13, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SimpleCaseIterDriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_dbcaserecorder.py", line 16, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SimpleCaseIterDriver, CaseIteratorDriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_json_filevar.py", line 12, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import CONMINdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_jsonrecorder.py", line 16, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import SensitivityDriver, CaseIteratorDriver, \
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cobyla.cobyla)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/casehandlers/test/test_query.py", line 15, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import FixedPointIterator, SLSQPdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from openmdao.lib.drivers.cobyladriver import COBYLAdriver
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg/openmdao/lib/drivers/cobyladriver.py", line 15, in <module>
        from cobyla.cobyla import cobyla, closeunit
    ImportError: No module named cobyla.cobyla

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_bar3')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_bar3'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_extra')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_extra'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_workflow_MDAO')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_workflow_MDAO'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_broydensolver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_broydensolver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_caseiterdriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_cobyladriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_cobyladriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_doedriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_doedriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_opt_conmin')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_opt_conmin'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_opt_newsumtinterruptible')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_opt_newsumtinterruptible'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_slsqpdriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_slsqpdriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_derivatives')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_derivatives'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_driver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_driver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_multidriver')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_multidriver'

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_problem_formulation')
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
        module = resolve_name(addr.module)
      File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.10.3.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_problem_formulation'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 651 tests in 25.830s

    FAILED (errors=24)
```

I hit a character limit including the cobyla setup.py output. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/0nUHnbE8`

Comment: In what way are you installing openmdao?  Are you pip installing it from pypi, or cloning it from github and running local pip?  Are you installing into system python or into an Anaconda environment?  I think I've seen this before with someone who had a problem with their system python, and that using Anaconda may have alleviated the problem.

Comment: I am installing openmdao by calling the .py file I downloaded from the openmdao archive.

If it makes a difference, I am installing version 10.3.2.py.

I'll take a look into using Anaconda - thanks for the response.

Comment: OH--0.10.3.2 is a version that is around two years old.  Do you have a specific reason for wanting that version, because our 1.6.4 version is a MUCH easier install.

Comment: And with that much, much older version, I'm not sure my advice on using Anaconda would help, as it would with our 1.x.x releases.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to use 10.3.2 - the software I am installing is not compatible with more recent versions. I'll hold off investigating Anaconda.

Comment: There's an old thread from our old forums on this error, don't know if it will help you or not: http://openmdao.org/forum/questions/2648/osx-cobyla-installation-failure-no-module-named-cobylacobyla

Comment: What software are you running that requires 0.10.3.2? If by chance it's one of mine (e.g. webcam pulse detector), the `no_openmdao` branch should be used
https://github.com/thearn/webcam-pulse-detector/tree/no_openmdao

Comment: As it turns out, I do not need 0.10.3.2; I instead need version 0.13.0 for a program called WISDEM. While installing this I ran into another issue which I've generated another post for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707847/plugin-issue-while-installing-version-0-13-0-of-openmdao

Comment: I was able to overcome my issue by starting over with a fresh install of Ubuntu and installing openmdao fresh. Thanks for all of your help!