# Plugin issue while installing version 0.13.0 of OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I recently posted about a cobyla problem with version 0.10.3 of OpenMDAO. Since then I've realized I need version 0.13.0. (This is for eventually using WISDEM). This go around, I am having trouble with plugins.

Here's the log for the installation of 0.13.0: http://pastebin.com/UAg2b7YG

Additionally, here's the output of executing 'openmdao test':

```
$ openmdao test 
...S.....S................................................................S..................S......................................................................................................S.S..S................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S..............................................................S...............................................................................................S........................S..SS.....................................................................................................................................................SS.S...........F..F...............................................................................................................................................................................................................
======================================================================
FAIL: test_basic (openmdao.main.test.test_plugins.PluginsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/test/test_plugins.py", line 169, in test_basic
    self.assertTrue('foobar.foobar.Foobar' in captured_stdout)
AssertionError: False is not true
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: D: 
root: D: test_basic
root: D: 
root: D: quickstart
root: D: 
root: D: makedist
root: I: Generating grammar tables from /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/sphinx/pycode/Grammar-py2.txt
root: I: Writing grammar tables to /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/sphinx/pycode/Grammar-py2-sphinx1.2.pickle
root: D: captured stdout:
root: D: Making output directory...
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org/dev/objects.inv...
building [html]: all source files
updating environment: 4 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 25%] index
reading sources... [ 50%] pkgdocs
reading sources... [ 75%] srcdocs
reading sources... [100%] usage

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 25%] index
writing output... [ 50%] pkgdocs
writing output... [ 75%] srcdocs
writing output... [100%] usage

writing additional files... (2 module code pages) _modules/index genindex py-modindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.
collecting entry point information...
Created distribution foobar-0.1.tar.gz

root: D: captured stderr:
root: D: 
root: D: captured subprocess output:
root: D: running sdist
running egg_info
creating src/foobar.egg-info
writing requirements to src/foobar.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/foobar.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/foobar.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/foobar.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating foobar-0.1
creating foobar-0.1/src
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
making hard links in foobar-0.1...
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> foobar-0.1
hard linking README.txt -> foobar-0.1
hard linking setup.cfg -> foobar-0.1
hard linking setup.py -> foobar-0.1
hard linking src/foobar/__init__.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar
hard linking src/foobar/foobar.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/requires.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/top_level.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/.buildinfo -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/genindex.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/index.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/objects.inv -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/pkgdocs.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/py-modindex.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/search.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/searchindex.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/srcdocs.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/usage.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/index.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/foobar.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test/test_foobar.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/index.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/pkgdocs.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/srcdocs.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/usage.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/ajax-loader.gif -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/basic.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment-bright.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment-close.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/default.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/doctools.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/down-pressed.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/down.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/file.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/jquery.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/minus.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/plus.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/pygments.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/searchtools.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/sidebar.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/underscore.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/up-pressed.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/up.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/websupport.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/test/__init__.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
hard linking src/foobar/test/test_foobar.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
copying setup.cfg -> foobar-0.1
Writing foobar-0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'foobar-0.1' (and everything under it)

root: D: 
root: D: makedist overwrite
root: D: captured stdout:
root: D: Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org/dev/objects.inv...
building [html]: all source files
updating environment: 4 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 25%] index
reading sources... [ 50%] pkgdocs
reading sources... [ 75%] srcdocs
reading sources... [100%] usage

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 25%] index
writing output... [ 50%] pkgdocs
writing output... [ 75%] srcdocs
writing output... [100%] usage

writing additional files... (2 module code pages) _modules/index genindex py-modindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.
collecting entry point information...
Removing existing distribution foobar-0.1.tar.gz
Created distribution foobar-0.1.tar.gz

root: D: captured stderr:
root: D: 
root: D: captured subprocess output:
root: D: running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/foobar.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/foobar.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/foobar.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/foobar.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating foobar-0.1
creating foobar-0.1/src
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
creating foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
making hard links in foobar-0.1...
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> foobar-0.1
hard linking README.txt -> foobar-0.1
hard linking setup.cfg -> foobar-0.1
hard linking setup.py -> foobar-0.1
hard linking src/foobar/__init__.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar
hard linking src/foobar/foobar.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/requires.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar.egg-info/top_level.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar.egg-info
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/.buildinfo -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/genindex.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/index.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/objects.inv -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/pkgdocs.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/py-modindex.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/search.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/searchindex.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/srcdocs.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/usage.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/index.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/foobar.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test/test_foobar.html -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_modules/foobar/test
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/index.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/pkgdocs.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/srcdocs.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources/usage.txt -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_sources
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/ajax-loader.gif -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/basic.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment-bright.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment-close.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/comment.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/default.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/doctools.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/down-pressed.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/down.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/file.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/jquery.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/minus.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/plus.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/pygments.css -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/searchtools.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/sidebar.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/underscore.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/up-pressed.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/up.png -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static/websupport.js -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/sphinx_build/html/_static
hard linking src/foobar/test/__init__.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
hard linking src/foobar/test/test_foobar.py -> foobar-0.1/src/foobar/test
copying setup.cfg -> foobar-0.1
Writing foobar-0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'foobar-0.1' (and everything under it)

root: D: 
root: D: install
root: D: captured stdout:
root: D: 
root: D: captured stderr:
root: D: 
root: D: captured subprocess output:
root: D: Processing foobar
Writing /tmp/tmpvM_j_j/foobar/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/tmpvM_j_j/foobar/egg-dist-tmp-whUqTd
creating /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar-0.1-py2.7.egg
Extracting foobar-0.1-py2.7.egg to /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding foobar 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar-0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for foobar==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for foobar==0.1

root: D: 
root: D: list
root: D: captured subprocess output:
root: D: 
Installed external driver and component plugins
-----------------------------------------------




root: D: 
root: D: uninstall
root: D: captured stdout:
root: D: Uninstalling foobar-0.1:
  /home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar-0.1-py2.7.egg
Proceed (y/n)?   Successfully uninstalled foobar-0.1

--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

======================================================================
FAIL: test_find_plugins (openmdao.main.test.test_plugins.PluginsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Downloads/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/test/test_plugins.py", line 448, in test_find_plugins
    self.assertEqual(sorted(expected.keys()), sorted(plugins.keys()))
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['openmdao.component', 'openmd... != []

First list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
openmdao.component

- ['openmdao.component', 'openmdao.container']
+ []

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1086 tests in 235.278s

FAILED (SKIP=16, failures=2)
```

Numpy comes up a lot, but I've verified I have it installed and updated. Any guidance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to overcome my issue by starting over with a fresh install of Ubuntu and installing openmdao fresh.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but I can't comment. As far as I know  wisdem is not compatible with v0.13 and requires 0.10.x. So before you spend too much time on 0.13 I'd suggest that you check that you've got the right version.